# the witcher 2: kayran infinite healing bug

Tags: the-witcher-2

When I fight the first boss, **Kayran** (difficulty: **Dark**, version: **3.3.3.1**, no mods), I attack the tentacles but they don't get cut. The life of the monster goes down a bit with each attack until disappointingly the bar returns full or almost full, in an infinite cycle. Nothing else happens.

How can I defeat Kayran?

Comment: -2? Really? Would you mind your own business or provide a constructive critique? Nobody else found a solution to this bug.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you already know the answer just post it.

Comment: The downvotes and close votes are probably due to not only stating intention to answer your own question in the question, but stating that answer in the comments as well. That is generally frowned upon here, even though answering your own question is acceptable and encouraged. If you'd have done neither of those, people would probably have thought nothing of it. The likely reasoning is it seems you already decided to accept your own answer rather than give others the opportunity to post a better one. On a side note, the comment/answer could use slight improvement when you actually post it.

Comment: @Zommuter only users with 15+ reputation can post an answer as they ask and only users with 100+ reputation can answer their own question without waiting 8 hours if they didn't instant answer. As lunadir has insufficient reputation to have done either, they must wait.

Comment: Exactly. I must wait 8 hours before posting an answer. I did not say that others cannot answer, although I higly doubt someone has something to say. Still, people may frown about my behavior, but a downvote without motivation is not good either.

Comment: @lunadir It is, however, completely acceptable.  You are free to answer your own question, but there's no reason to add that to your question.  It makes it sound like you don't actually have a problem that needs solving.

Comment: @skovacs1 I see, that's not stated on the [privileges site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Hm, strange restrictions. Anyway, sorry #lunadir for the harsh comment then

Comment: @fbueckert If I had the possibility to answer immediatly, I wouldn't have said it, but since it'll require some time I thought it would be useful to tell people I actually had the solution. In this way I avoid wasting people's time trying to solve a problem which has been already solved. I would have deleted the comment and the "I will answer" immediately after posting said answer. It's not beautiful, but it's better than the alternative.

Comment: @Zommuter It should probably be added there. It is clearly documented on the [self-answer help page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Has anyone thought to help this guy by just coping and pasting his answer in a block quote for him? I understand that her wouldn't get rep but it is better than badgering him.

Comment: @Cole Give a man a fish, and feed him for a day.  *Teach* a man to fish, and feed him for a lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: I was about to give up when I tried to see what would happen fighting the boss without wearing anything except for the silver sword and the eventual kayran trap.
For me it works **but** if i can't cut a tentacle the at the first try then I have to restart the fight, possibly restarting the game entirely.